# assets issue in rails 6 for grape-swagger-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger

grape-rails-swagger used to work fine with rails 5

but now with rails 6 lots of things have changed with webpacker now its giving error

```
Showing /home/faisal-nfl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/grape-swagger-rails-0.3.1/app/views/grape_swagger_rails/application/index.html.erb where line #7 raised:

Asset `grape_swagger_rails/application.css` was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Declare links to your assets in `app/assets/config/manifest.js`.

  //= link grape_swagger_rails/application.css
and restart your server
```

I even tried to follow instructions in error but same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why but, I had to add these at top of `app/assets/config/manifest.js`

```
//= link grape_swagger_rails/application.css
//= link grape_swagger_rails/application.js
```

so `app/assets/config/manifest.js` looks like this now

```
//= link grape_swagger_rails/application.css
//= link grape_swagger_rails/application.js
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

its working now